# How to customize unity's lenses - e.g. to search photos in one directory?

Tags: 12.04, unity, configuration, lenses

I would like to be able to customize Unity's lenses, for instance to make Photo lens to search for photos in directories that I mark and the same rule for the music lens.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the Music lens I'm certain it doesn't work that way.
The lens doesn't display the music files you have in a folder somewhere. It reads the index from banshee and rhythmbox so only tracks you have in there are displayed in the music lens.

Since you use clementine, I've dug around and found that somebody is actually writing a scope for it, so you can use 'unity-lens-music' with clementine.

https://launchpad.net/~markjtully/+archive/ppa

It is work in progress and doesn't work for me so far (I've installed it with clementine, to see if it works). It displays search results when you type, but it isn't able to start playback in clementine when you click on the song. Maybe you can find some additional help for that.
To install the scope type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clementine-scope
```

Comment: I use Clementine for the music files so that's not a good option for me(but maybe I will just add music files to banshee or rhythmbox and don't open it) and for the photos I would like to find other solution than you suggested.